# Cant upload image in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

Hi im trying to upload image into database when i do this all its gave error like this.

> (1/1) BadMethodCallException
>   Method getClientOrignalName does not exist.

```
<form action="{{route('post.store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">**strong text**
```

public function store(Request $request)
    {

```
    $this->validate($request,[


     'title'  => 'required|max:255',
     'content' => 'required',
     'feature' => 'required|image',
     'category_id' => 'required' 



    ]);
        // dd($request->all());
         //exit;

    $featured = $request->feature;
    $featured_new_name=time().$featured->getClientOrignalName();

    $featured->move('uploads/posts',$featured_new_name);

    $post = Post::create([

    'title'=>$request->title,
    'content'=>$request->content,
    'feature'=>'uploads/posts/'. $featured_new_name,
    'category_id'=>$request->category_id

    ]);

    Session::flash('success','Post Created Successfully.');


}
```

Comment: `getClientOrignalName` is a typo. `Original`, not `Orignal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use file() method for retrieve file information from request. Try this code,

```
public function store(Request $request) {

    $this->validate($request,[
        'title'  => 'required|max:255',
        'content' => 'required',
        'feature' => 'required|image',
        'category_id' => 'required' 

    ]);

    // use file() method for retrive file data
    $featured = $request->file('feature');

    $featured_new_name = time() . $featured->getClientOrignalName();

    $featured->move('uploads/posts', $featured_new_name);

    $post = Post::create([
        'title'=>$request->title,
        'content'=>$request->content,
        'feature'=>'uploads/posts/'. $featured_new_name,
        'category_id'=>$request->category_id
    ]);

    Session::flash('success','Post Created Successfully.');
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for trying to help OP! Could you please add some more information to this answer by editing it, for example what did you change and why did you change that part. This would greatly help others who might stumble upon this question later.