# can't upload image by ajax in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

iam try to upload image by ajax in laravel.
here is my js code :

```
$('#profile_picture').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{url('all/update-profile-picture')}}", 
        data:new FormData(this),
        dataType:'json',
        type:'post',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache:false,
    }).done( function(data){
      //swal("Good job!", "Your information has been successfully updated!", "success")
          console.log('Ajax was Successful!')
          console.log(data)
    }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, error){
        console.log(textStatus)
        console.log(error)
    });
});
```

here is controller code :

```
$validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'profile_photo'=> 'required|image|mimies:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048'
]);
if ($validation->passes()) {
    //$image = $request->file('profile_photo');
    $new_name = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $request->image->move(public_path("photo"),$new_name);
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Image uploaded successfully'
    ]);
} else {
    return response()->json([
        'message' => $validation->errors()->all(),
        'profile_photo' => '',
        'class_name' => 'danger'
    ]);
}
```

I hope its my controller's problem . when click submit with blank , its seen error message in console.

I don't understand whats the problem ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use file() method for get your request file.

```
$validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'profile_photo'=> 'required|image|mimies:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048'
]);

if ($validation->passes()) {

    $new_name = time().'.'.$request->file('profile_photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $request->file('profile_photo')->move(public_path("photo"),$new_name);

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Image uploaded successfully'
    ]);
} 

return response()->json([
    'message' => $validation->errors()->all(),
    'profile_photo' => '',
    'class_name' => 'danger'
]);
```

Comment: i see `Internal Server Error` in console

Comment: iam sure my problem is `if ($validation->passes()) {` in this condition & i did successfully upload image without check validation.

Comment: Can you exactly see the error by inspect element then go to network tab then click on the request.

Comment: You can see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53948142/cant-upload-image-in-laravel-5-4/53948257#53948257

Comment: Did you import Validator class, top of your controller class ?

Comment: hey , my mistake is `mimies`. correct is `mimes`. thanks for supporting